# Get the name tag from an input with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the following input that I want to parse using `JSOUP`

> `input type="text" class="W50pc Validate_TimeUnits  " name="TimeUnits" id="TimeUnits" value="3"`

And I want to get the value of the `name` tag, but I don't seem to find the function for it. Here is my approach:

```
for (Element input : document.getElementsByTag("input")) {
    Log.d("Element " + i, input.className() + " - " + input.val());
    i++;
}
```

I can get the values for `id`, `value` or `class`, but I can't get the function for the `name` tag. Can anyone guide me to the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the `attr(...)` method:

```
for (Element input : document.getElementsByTag("input")) {
    Log.d("Element " + i, input.attr("name"));
    i++;
}
```